# How pass 'templating' component for service as argument?

Tags: symfony

I have a method in 'DynamicList' service that should return a select filled with dynamic data, but i'm getting "circular reference":

YML:

```
parameters:
    my.dynamic_list.class: My\DynamicListBundle\Service\DynamicList

services:
    my.dynamic_list:
        class: %my.dynamic_list.class%
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager','@templating']
```

Class:

```
<?php

namespace My\DynamicListBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;

class DynamicList
{
    private $em;
    private $templating;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManager $em,
        EngineInterface $templating
    ) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function getSelect($slug)
    {
        $dynamic_list = $this->em
            ->getRepository('MyDynamicListBundle:DynamicList')
            ->findOneBy(array(
                "slug" => $slug
            ));

        return $this->templating->render('MyComponentsCoreBundle::Templates/DynamicList/combo.html.twig', array(
            'dl' => $dynamic_list
        ));
    }
}
```

I guess i don't need to put here the twig content: the problema occurs before.

Last, the error i'm getting:

```
Circular reference detected for service "my.dynamic_list", path: "my.dynamic_list -> templating -> twig". (500 Internal Server Error - ServiceCircularReferenceException)
```

What's the proper way to get templating component working in my service?

Comment: According to [this comment](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2347#issuecomment-2838590) it's easier to inject the whole service container if you need the templating service.

Comment: OK, I will do this because I need get progress... But i'm afraid to inject container (http://goo.gl/PD0jVN).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a workaround but I don't if is the best way:

```
<?php

namespace My\DynamicListBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;

class DynamicList
{
    private $em;
    private $templating;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManager $em
    ) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function init(
        EngineInterface $templating
    ) {
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function getSelect($slug)
    {
        $dynamic_list = $this->em
            ->getRepository('MyDynamicListBundle:DynamicList')
            ->findOneBy(array(
                "slug" => $slug
            ));

        return $this->templating->render('MyComponentsCoreBundle::Templates/DynamicList/combo.html.twig', array(
            'dl' => $dynamic_list
        ));
    }
}
```

So, in controller, I call 'init()' to pass 'templating':

```
$dl_service = $this->get('my.dynamic_list');
$dl_service->init($this->container->get('templating'));
```